# My Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt was updated by someone and contains an other name and the false ppa

Tags: application-development, quickly, development, application-submission

For the Ubuntu App Showdown I created a Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt-File and uploaded it correctly on "My Apps" to participate the Ubuntu App Showdown - Contest. Now I saw, that my .txt-file was changed by someone, because there is a false name and PPA. The txt-file contains an other participant which is listed in app#122 with the app-name "Variety" on [Swhodown Apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/apps/). The correct app should be my app#38 "Interest Calculation" for my app you can find on [My app link](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1172/).
I posted this in the Feedback-section but I am not sure if somewone reads this becauseI got no answers of my other questions, I posted there more than one week ago.
I don't want to be rejected from the contest, because someone has updated my .txt-file. The correct content for the .txt-file is also listed in the Feedback-section of my app. This is the copy of original text I uploaded, when I created the app-entry in the developer portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of Variety wallpaper changer ([app entry is here](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1151/)). Yes, seems your application entry is pointing to the exact same "Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details_16.txt" file that mine points to. I don't know how this has happened, but can't you just click "Edit" for this section (the link for editing the section is probably: https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1172/update/?step=about) and then upload the correct txt file?

Comment: I changed it! But now the change is also awaiting review!

Comment: Don't worry, we do take great care in reviewing each app. We saw that, and your app qualified for the contest with the right PPA details. For reference, this was a bug in MyApps: https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1022697